# Is there any Android API to detect face inside an image?

Tags: android, android-studio, image-processing, image-recognition

Is there any Android API to detect face inside an image? For exemple on iOS there is such API to detect face, and I‘m curious if there is a similar API in Android.

Comment: there is this: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection/android

Comment: Not through Android SDK itself, but you can use ML-Kit for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android framework has the [FaceDetector](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector) API, although is only suitable for bitmaps (not real-time), and returns only the boundaries (rectangle) location.

For more advanced features, such as real-time detection or face features contour, there is the [ML Kit library](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection) offered by Google. Although this library can also be used for very simple use cases, such as also getting the face location in a bitmap.

More about ML Kit in the next link:
https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/guides

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I think the ML Kit Library is not free right ?

Comment: but as fare as i know, the face detection are based on the google vision API and they are not free ? you must provide an API key ?

Comment: I believe you are confusing it with the old "ML Kit for Firebase", so beware of pricing references in the Internet as they may refer to the old API. The new ML Kit although it shares the name, is in fact a new product which you may use or not with Firebase, and yes it is free of charge. I've placed the home link at the bottom of the answer. And a screenshot marking in red the actual line stating it is free.